# how do javascript functions parameter work under the hood

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and am unable to find any good explanation on parameter/arguments, how they work under the hood. For eg:

```
function changeStuff(a) {
        return a = a * 10;
      }

var num = 10;
console.log(changeStuff(num)); //prints 100
console.log(num); //prints 10
```

When I call this `changeStuff` function, how does javascript put variable num into parameter - a? Does it do something like `a = num` under the hood?

I'm sorry if its a bad or a dumb question.

Comment: The argument `a` will have the value of `num` which is `10`. so the function will calculate `10 * 10` and returns the result.

Comment: you would need to see compiled code rather than this interpreted code to understand it more, as you don´t even deal with registers here. If it works same way as c++ (probably similar), when calling a function, function parameters are pushed onto current stack. Then the function reads values from the stack according to the amount and function reads/writes those values

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: @juvian that should be an answer. Great explanation.

Comment: @Thielicious, so inside javascript engine it is saying `num =  a`? It is just abstracted away from us?

Comment: More like `a = num` as the outer scope variable is being  referenced basically

Comment: oh, okay i think I understand better now . Thanks alot guys !

Comment: @Paul maybe I went a bit too much under the hood though ^^

Comment: @juvian yeah .. a little too under the hood .. but its my mistake, i should have said inside the javascript engine rather than under the hood .. though, im pretty sure what you have answered is pretty much correct if I could understand it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to see compiled code rather than this interpreted code to understand it more, as you don´t even deal with registers here.

Assuming it works same way as c++ (probably similar), when calling a function, function parameters are pushed onto current stack. Then the function reads values from the stack according to the amount and function reads/writes those values.

In compiled code, there will not exist such thing as 'a' variable. Only a limited amount of registers are available, so a will actually be one of those. Before assigning that, the value from the register will be pushed onto the stack, so that when function ends, the register can go back to its previous value for the running code that might have been using it before calling the function.

[A bit of literature on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript copies the reference to the function `a * 10` to the variable `a` in this case. So `a` is `a * 10` then and so `a * 10` will evaluated and returned.

Comment: Except `10` is a primitive value and those are `passed by value` in javascript; if they were passed by reference as you say the `num` var would be modified by the function.

Comment: a * 10 is a function. a will get a reference to the function a * 10.  a function is an (complex) object. If you have a complex type, even if it contains primitive types, it will be passed by reference. num will be passed to a in the function a * 10 as value, a in the return statement will get the reference to the function.

Comment: thanks, i guess i have to look up pass by value/reference thoroughly, maybe that will help me understand what going on